# D3 bar chart with linked bars (like sankey)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, nvd3.js

How do I connect the [bars](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304) with a smooth Bezier curve similar to a [sankey](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/ca9a0bb7ba204d12974bca90acc507c0)?

[image: nvd3 discrete bar chart w shaded area]

[image: sankey diagram]

My approach is to customize the [nvd3 discrete bar chart](http://nvd3.org/examples/discreteBar.html) with [D3 Links api](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#links) but I am struggling.

Here's the base [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Polyoptik/kwdL83LL/) I am trying to incorporate the following from the [D3 Sankey plugin](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5028304). I assume this is a decent approach.

```
sankey.link = function() {
    var curvature = .5;

    function link(d) {
      var x0 = d.source.x + d.source.dx,
          x1 = d.target.x,
          xi = d3.interpolateNumber(x0, x1),
          x2 = xi(curvature),
          x3 = xi(1 - curvature),
          y0 = d.source.y + d.sy + d.dy / 2,
          y1 = d.target.y + d.ty + d.dy / 2;
      return "M" + x0 + "," + y0
           + "C" + x2 + "," + y0
           + " " + x3 + "," + y1
           + " " + x1 + "," + y1;
    }

    link.curvature = function(_) {
      if (!arguments.length) return curvature;
      curvature = +_;
      return link;
    };

    return link;
  };
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.